# Neo4j merge nodes by relationship

Tags: neo4j, merge, nodes, graph-databases

I have big dataset of persons data and found a lot of duplicates by an algorithm.
I marked these duplicates in Neo4j with a relationship.
Example:
(p:Person)-[:similar]->(d:Person)

For testing purpose I created virtual nodes by combining all nodes marked with the similar-relationship.

```sql
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('Person', 'similar', {})
YIELD nodeId, setId
WITH setId AS idd, collect(algo.getNodeById(nodeId)) AS nodis
WHERE size(nodis) > 1
CALL apoc.nodes.collapse(nodis,{properties:'combine'}) YIELD from, rel
RETURN idd, from, rel
```

Here I found the problem, that only two nodes were compared and stored in the result data.
Example:

ID: 5, Peter Smith
ID: 4635, Peter Smit

ID: 4635, Peter Smit
ID: 765, Peter Smith

ID: 5, Peter Smith
ID: 765, Peter Smith

I want to refactor the graph and merge the duplicates (a forrest) into one node. But only one node is merged. How can I merge all forrests, that exist due to the relationship 'similar'?

### UPDATE:

I found a semi solution. All similar persons were merged by the following code. All properties were combined as a list. Seems fine to me, except, that the Ids are in a list now, too - but this isn't the topic of the question.

```sql
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('Person', 'similar', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
WITH setId AS idd, collect(algo.getNodeById(nodeId)) AS nodis
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodis, {properties:'combine', mergeRels: true}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using constraints unique?

I also faced same problems with MERGE.

example)

CREATE CONSTRAINT ON ( book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead); instead, provide [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that don't require clarification from the asker.